# How to convert repeated simulated data from arrays to list

Tags: r

I simulated repeated data using `replicate` function, as follows:

`mydata <-repllicate(100, mysimfun)`

Then to access the first data, I have to use `mydata[,,1]`.

I would like to convert my data to be stored as a list. Hence, I can access my data like this:

`mydata[[1]]`.

I used `as.list(mydata)` but it converted the observations to list. I need the `100` repeated data to be a list of `100` datasets.

I have already got the data, I would like to convert it to a list. I generate it last week before I know the idea of `simplify` in replicate. Now, I did some works with this data. Since I have many functions which work with a list, I would like to convert the same data to the list, to save my time.

Is there any idea, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `simplify` argument in `replicate` which by default is `TRUE` resulting in `array`.  If we change it to `FALSE`, it returns a `list`

```
mydata <-replicate(100, mysimfun, simplify = FALSE)
```

As a reproducible example

```
set.seed(24)
replicate(3, sample(5), simplify = FALSE)
```

---

If the 'mydata' is already an `array`, then we can loop through the 3rd dimension and extract the elements

```
set.seed(24)
mydata <- replicate(3, matrix(rnorm(5*10), 5, 10))
mydata1 <- lapply(seq_len(dim(mydata)[3]), function(i) mydata[,,i])
```

Comment: I have already simulated a data which takes a time (say an hour to be generated). Is there a way to convert it to a list?

Comment: @Silver_80  Updated the post